# combine three operations with WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Сan't understand how to combine three operations that depend on each other.

I have new User that need to save to the base:

1. gets the item from the base.

   > ```
   >   roleRepo.findByName("USER"); // return Mono<Role>
   >
   >   user.setRole(...); // set result from roleRepo.findByName("USER") is String
   > ```
2. saves to the base with data from first operation

   ```
         userRepo.save(user); // return Mono<User>
   ```
3. save to the base new UserRole

   ```
         UserRole uRole = new UserRole();
         urole.setUserId(user.getId); 
         urole.setRoleId(role.Id);  
         userRolesRepo.save(uRole) // return Mono<UserRole>
   ```

And finally method returns

```
 Mono<User>
```

to controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine async operations by using flatmap. Try to use them like chains, avoid nesting.

Not tested but this should give you a headstart:

```java
roleRepo.findByName("USER")
        .flatMap(role -> {
            user.setRole(role);
            return Mono.just(user);
        })
        .flatMap(user -> userRepo.save(user))
        .flatMap(user -> {
            UserRole uRole = new UserRole();
            urole.setUserId(user.getId); 
            urole.setRoleId(role.Id);
            return Mono.zip(Mono.just(user), userRolesRepo.save(uRole));
        })
        .flatMap(data -> Mono.just(data.getT1()));
```